# "no build stage in current context" despite I specified the directory

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I am trying to run GitHub Actions with Windows:

```yaml
name: Build on Windows

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build Docker image
        run: docker build -t my-image:${{ github.sha }} -f windows/Dockerfile.windows .

      - name: Start Docker container
        run: docker run -v %cd%:/app my-image:${{ github.sha }} make OS=windows ARCH=amd64 msi
```

I get the error:

```
Run docker build -t my-image:2badf5294f371e423b064e4a014e175a91f1f5cf -f windows/Dockerfile.windows .
  docker build -t my-image:2badf5294f371e423b064e4a014e175a91f1f5cf -f windows/Dockerfile.windows .
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
Error response from daemon: no build stage in current context
Sending build context to Docker daemon  328.2kB
```

It is weird, because I did specify the build directory `.`.

`Dockerfile.windows`:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri \
    "https://github.com/XXX/mingw64-distrib/releases/download/v10.0.0/mingw-w64-v10.0.0.tar.bz2" -OutFile "mingw-w64.tar.bz2"
RUN Expand-Archive -Path "mingw-w64.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\mingw64"
ENV PATH += ";C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin"

# ...
```

Comment: Put `FROM` as first line